# iOS Location status message on background doesn't show

Tags: ios, background, statusbar

I've implemented a CLLocation like waze to get the users location on background mode, I want to show the bar like "incall" showing that I'm getting the location.

I don't know why the bar doesn't show, I have in the info.plist this

> Key : NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are talking about the blue "navigation" bar that appears under the status bar.

That only appears when an app is being used for navigation. An app that simply gets location in the background does not show the blue bar (or any other color bar).

Comment: Yes I was talking about that, What do you mean with "navigation", I'm very new in it.

Comment: The blue bar only appears when an app is currently being used to provide navigation (directions) from one location to another.

Comment: Oh ok, sorry me and my poor knowledge, I'm very grateful with you, Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad I can help. Indicate the question is answered by accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you `requestAlwaysAuthorization` the bar will not appear (because you could use location services at any time). The bar appears only when you `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` and the app asks to keep receiving location updates while in the background.

See the documentation for [requestWhenInUseAuthorization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/requestWhenInUseAuthorization) (emphasis added):

> If the user grants “when-in-use” authorization to your app, your app
>   can start most (but not all) location services while it is in the
>   foreground. (Apps cannot use any services that automatically relaunch
>   the app, such as region monitoring or the significant location change
>   service.) When started in the foreground, services continue to run in
>   the background if your app has enabled background location updates in
>   the Capabilities tab of your Xcode project. Attempts to start location
>   services while your app is running in the background will fail. **The
>   system displays a location-services indicator in the status bar when
>   your app moves to the background with active location services**.

This line about the "location-services indicator" is notably absent from the documentation for [requestAlwaysAuthorization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/requestAlwaysAuthorization).